# Run a web page containing WebGL in an executable file without using a browser

Tags: javascript, windows, webgl, exe

I wonder if it is possible to run a WebGL website without preinstalled browsers. I thought the WebBrowser of Visual Studio might help, but I read that it uses the Engine of Internet Explorer in compatibility mode, therefore I cannot run WebGL with that. Any ideas?

Comment: Something has to render the content - its possible you could write your own, but reusing an existing render engine will save you from reinventing the wheel. Just pick one with a good rep and that handles your content well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned Visual Studio, have you seen [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/)?
([Github](https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet))

From the page:

> WebKit .NET is a WinForms control library wrapper for WebKit written in C#. The aim is to make it easy for developers to incorporate WebKit into their .NET applications.

If this turns out not to work, searching for something along the same lines is probably your best bet.

**Edit**:

[DotNetBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser) is another Chromium based component that looks a bit more up to date. But, it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

[Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron) might work. It's basically Chromium + IO.js